# How to append files in different directories PHP

Tags: php, file, append

I have a file on my desktop I want to append. How would I go about doing this?

Typing `../../../../../../../` doesn't work, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path to those directories, such as:

```
C:\Users\Mike\Documents\code
```

or

```
/home/mike/Desktop/code/dir1
```